# JNDI lookups (or equivalent) in Java Azure Functions

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, jndi

Is there a way to access system properties or JNDI resources at runtime in the Azure functions environment with Java?  A fairly standard practice is to define your datasources and other MQ connections etc in JNDI resources since they are generally environment specific.  I was wondering how we can achieve this in the "serverless" Azure Functions environment. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java#environment-variables) for information on how to access system variables from a Java Functions